# swift How to determine if a variable is an optional

Tags: swift, option-type

I want to know if a variable is an optional

I try method below, but fail

```
func isOptional(v: Any) -> Bool {
    return v is Optional
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem...  I mean... you can tell at compile time...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a generic is an optional in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064644/how-to-determine-if-a-generic-is-an-optional-in-swift) (specifically, `Any` can't be optional, but a generic could be optional)

Comment: @nhgrif thank you for comment. I see this problem too.

I am a newbee on swift, it's hard to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an academic exercise (can it be done vs. should it be done), I came up with this:

```
func isOptional(a: Any) -> Bool {
    return "\(a.dynamicType)".hasPrefix("Swift.Optional")
}
```

Example:

```
let name = "Fred"
let oname: String? = "Jones"
let age = 37
let oage: Int? = 38

let arr: [Any] = [name, oname, age, oage]

for item in arr {
    println("\(item) \(isOptional(item))")
}
```

Output:

```
Fred false
Optional("Jones") true
37 false
Optional(38) true
```

Would I recommend using this in production code?  No.  I recommend staying away from `Any` if at all possible, and I wouldn't bet on the output of `dynamicType` remaining the same.