# How to check if nested optional is nil in generic class?

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

I have simple class:

```
class Values<T> {
    let new: T
    let old: T?

    init(new: T, old: T? = nil) {
        self.new = new
        self.old = old
    }

    func changed<TProp: AnyObject>(_ getter: (T) -> TProp) -> Bool {
        return old == nil || !(getter(old!) === getter(new))
    }

    func changed<TProp: Equatable>(_ getter: (T) -> TProp) -> Bool {
        return old == nil || !(getter(old!) == getter(new))
    }
}
```

When using it as `Values<ChartViewModelData?>` where ChartViewModelData is a class i got problems when old is nested optional - it is both nil and not equal to nil:

[image: xcode console]

So changing function like this doesn't help:

```
return old == nil || old! == nil || !(getter(old!) === getter(new))
```

nil shouldn't be passed to the getter function, and i don't know how to achieve it.

**Reproduce:**

```
class PropClass {}

class TestClass {
    var someProp = PropClass()
}

let values = Values<TestClass?>(new: TestClass(), old: Optional<Optional<TestClass>>(nil))
values.changed({ $0!.someProp }) /* Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value */
values.changed({ $0?.someProp }) /* error: cannot convert value of type '(TestClass?) -> PropClass?' to expected argument type '(TestClass?) -> _' */
```

Second error appears because it can't use === on two Optional.

Comment: What does `getter` do, exactly?

Comment: @Alexander returns some property of the object, and changed func returns if it was changed in new value if compare to old one.

Comment: Can you give us some test cases to work with?

Comment: if values.changed({ $0!.chart }) {
    // handle chart changed
}

Comment: I think in the `old! == nil` code, what's being called is the `==` overload of type `(X?, X?) -> Bool`, where the runtime type of `X` is `T?`, which makes the operator actually have type `(T??, T??) -> Bool`, and what's being compared is `Optional.some(Optional.none)` and `Optional.none`, which are not equivalent.

Comment: That's not a test case "I can work with"

Comment: Also, it seems like what you're inventing here is going to lead you to the path of discovering Rx and reactive programming. I definitely suggest you look into those!

Comment: Thanks, i know about rx but can't use libs in current project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189987/discussion-between-alexander-and-alexander-danilov).

Answer (score 0):

Just spent couple of hours looking for a solution to the similar problem and I think I have finally found one. To check if nested value is `nil` for generic type you can use this:

```
if (newValue as AnyObject) is NSNull { 
    //value is nil
}
```